# AuthName with expression in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, authentication, apache2

According to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authname), in apache 2.5 it should be possible to use expressions in the `AuthName` directive when performing authentication, e.g.

```
AuthName "%{REQUEST_URI}"
```

In this case, it should be possible to treat dynamic requests. In the example the variable REQUEST_URI can take different value according to the request, e.g. being `pageone` for `www.mysite.com/pageone` and `pagetwo` for `www.mysite.com/pagetwo`. Unfortunately, apache 2.5 is still in development. Is there any workaround or upgrade to do in order to obtain the same behaviour in apache 2.4?